# commons-logging-1.1.jar; cannot read zip file entry

Tags: java, gwt, maven

I have imported a GWT project from GIT , but when i run maven Install 
it says

```
.m2\repository\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.1\commons-logging-1.1.jar; cannot read zip file entry
```

and if i simply run my application , i get this

```
\git\my-Search-Engine\qsse\war}: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/inject/servlet/GuiceServletContextListener
```

I tried to find out the way , one solution i found was to move the guice-servlet-3.0 from build path to \qsse\war\webinf\lib

but if i do that i start getting this exception

```
  ava.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/inject/Injector
```

any idea how can i resolve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For first question:

Can you open it in a WinZip or other compression tool.

Try deleting that `jar` and build again. Let Maven download it a fresh.

For Second Questin:

Which GWT version are you using ?

1. Verify that the required JAR is in your `classpath` including `guice.jar` and `guice-servlet-3.0.jar`

And also, `guice-servlet-3.0.jar` **should not be in you launch configuration** classpath. It has to be in your project classpath.

Comment: thanks , open what in a compression tool and how will i do that

Comment: Yes, Open it just to check whether it is corrupt or not.

Comment: Try deleting that `jar` and build again. Let Maven download it a fresh.

Answer (score 0):

For the second question, can you also move the other guice jars to webinf\lib ? (guice-3.0.jar should be missing)

Comment: thanks , you are right , but all the jars are missing infact , so i need to keep this process for every jar one by one , thats why i am trying to build maven , so it will produce the jars in target folder and then i can copy all the jars from target