# maven build failure: cannot read zip file entry

Tags: maven

i am getting this exception when try to run as-> maven build

```
 .m2\repository\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.1\commons-logging-1.1.jar; cannot read zip file entry
```

I've already spent a day on it , searched over google , but no luck

any idea how can i resolve this

thanks

Comment: Asking same question multiple times is nor good practice . Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10083482/commons-logging-1-1-jar-cannot-read-zip-file-entry/10084339#comment12913134_10084339

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to open the jar with a Zip utility (7Zip ou something else).

If it fails, delete the file from your local repository, and retry to run your app.

If it fails again, then you may have an issue with your Maven repos config.

Answer (score 2):

If maven downloads corrupt jars (jars that do not open with a zip utility) - try downloading those perticular jars manually and replace them in the appropriate repository folder location. 
In settings.xml specify the localRepository path explicitly. Using the default settings (i.e. not specifing localRepository) causes maven to download the jars again and again when you do a "clean install" and you end up have the corrupt jars again.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, it is caused by a corrupted zip file. A failed build often appends to the jar, but doesn't delete it, therefore producing an unreadable file.

The solution, as suggested, is to delete the jar, then try to download again from the repository (create a maven build with package goal) If that repeatedly fails, the remote location might be corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the m2 repository folder and try running your maven ,it will download all the jar files again and the build success